# C# Print word number of times depending on the input value

Tags: c#, loops, user-input

> Print the word in the program the number of times given by the user.

This is my attempt:

```
Console.Write("Enter the number of times to print \"word!\": ");
int number = Console.ReadLine();

if(number > 0)
    Console.WriteLine("word!"*number)
```

This does not work. How could I achieve this?

Comment: look for a `for` loop.

Comment: tom_ek please consider accepting an answer if it solved your question. You can do that by clicking the green check mark next to it

Answer (score 2):

You need to execute the statement the number of times the user has specified, for this C# has a few very convenient ways. Among them are:

A [`for`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx) loop:

```
Console.Write("Enter the number of times to print \"word!\": ");
int number = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

for(int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    Console.WriteLine("word!")
```

Or a [`while`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2aeyhxcd.aspx) loop:

```
while(number > 0){
    Console.WriteLine("word!")
    number--;
}
```

Also notice that [`Console.ReadLine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a `string`, and you need an `int`. To remedy this I used [`Int32.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `word` is a variable, try:

```
 Console.Write("Enter the word: ");
 string word= Console.ReadLine();

 Console.Write("Enter the number of times to print "+word+": ");
 int number=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

 for(int i=0;i<number;i++)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(word);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate for number times in order to show the word.
Something like:

```
        Console.Write("Enter the number of times to print \"word!\": ");
        int number = Console.ReadLine();

        if(number>0)
        { 
           for(int i=0;i<number;i++)
           {
            Console.WriteLine("word!");
           }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach to this, I wanted to Print a sentence a number of times.
First the program will ask you "Enter what you want to print" and then it will ask you to verify that how many times you want your text to be printed.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter what you want to print!");
    string userPrint = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of times you want to print: ");
    int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    while(number > 0){
        Console.WriteLine(userPrint);
        number--;
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: @slfan When you edit the answer, you could format it as well.